# Best way to start Mobile/IOS development for a .net shop

Tags: .net, ios, objective-c, mobile

We are a full .net shop, and are thinking about starting development of mobile apps for iphone/ipad.  Should we get into Objective C or are there IDE tools that would be easier to adopt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com).  It lets you code in C# and develop for iOS and Android using Windows as your OS.  It even lets you use Visual Studio as your IDE.  You still need a Mac as a build server, but you can buy a Mac Mini and stick it in the corner.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a learning curve required with iOS, but I think it is worth it. There will always be limitations with products like Xamarin. If you are looking to get a single quick app out, Xamarin may be fine, but otherwise, learn iOS...it is much easier to learn now than when I started 4 years ago with the NDA issues. Plus you have ARC now meaning you don't have to worry as much about memory management issues.